# what exactly should be certificate hash materials? verify x.509 certificate

Tags: cryptography, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, verify

So the hash materials are TBS certificate field. is This field values should be asn.1 decoded values or asn.1 encoded values? and id is '1.2.840.113549.1.1.5' or 'sha1RSA' ??

```
      TBSCertificate  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
    version         [0]  EXPLICIT Version DEFAULT v1,
    serialNumber         CertificateSerialNumber,
    signature            AlgorithmIdentifier,
    issuer               Name,
    validity             Validity,
    subject              Name,
    subjectPublicKeyInfo SubjectPublicKeyInfo,
    issuerUniqueID  [1]  IMPLICIT UniqueIdentifier OPTIONAL,
                         -- If present, version MUST be v2 or v3
    subjectUniqueID [2]  IMPLICIT UniqueIdentifier OPTIONAL,
                         -- If present, version MUST be v2 or v3
    extensions      [3]  EXPLICIT Extensions OPTIONAL
                         -- If present, version MUST be v3
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by [RFC5280 section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1)

> For signature, the data that is to be signed is encoded using the ASN.1 encoding rules (DER) [X.690].  ASN.1 DER encoding is a tag, length, value encoding system for each element.

So it should be asn.1 encoded values.

As for the signing algorithms, RFC5280 specifies supported algorithms in [section 4.1.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.1.2). There are references to 3 other RFCs.

i.e. RFC5280 contains an example of self-signed certificate where signing algorithm used was [sha1-with-rsa-signature (1.2.840.113549.1.1.5)](http://www.oid-info.com/cgi-bin/display?oid=1.2.840.113549.1.1.5&action=display).

Comment: So asn.1 encoded DER format tbs certificate fields should hashed. But my signature not match that hash.

Comment: Section 4.1.1.3 says `The signatureValue field contains a digital signature computed upon the ASN.1 DER encoded tbsCertificate. The ASN.1 DER encoded tbsCertificate is used as the input to the signature function.` You are probably doing something wrong :). Try to open the corresponding data with [asn.1 editor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4910/ASN-Editor)

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/neoeinstein/bouncycastle/blob/00ccedf8f4537a8621944f3072453e4603d09c4b/crypto/test/src/asn1/test/CertificateTest.cs#L199) is an example of CheckCertificate from bouncycastle sources.

Comment: im writing on pure python. can u explain how to hash tbs certificate fields.

Comment: DEcrypt RSA : 0x1ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff003021300906052b0e03021a050004140f83568d44ced9cfd0cd3d4eb6305b9bbca0560c is last 20bytes. SO my certificate hash should be 0f83568d.. bla bla 0560c

Answer (score 0):

HERE IS MY OWN CERTIFICATE 
    `

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

`

AND this is my decrypted signature  :

0x1ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff003021300906052b0e03021a05000414752d3360bc92e11322e1fa540b4a88e8c8b1f6f6
pure hash: 752d3360bc92e11322e1fa540b4a88e8c8b1f6f6 ==TBS certificate hash should be like this

and I calculate BASE64 decode get DER certificate. THEN FILTER TBS certificate and (byte code) sha1 hash. Then convert hex=752d3360bc92e11322e1fa540b4a88e8c8b1f6f6. THANKS @PEPO